# How to add github link in moderncv template

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to add github link and icon in `moderncv` classic template.

I'd like to add it to place at `additional information`. 
[image: as in this image]

I'm using :

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\faGithub\href{https://github.com/}{name}
```

but it doesn't add at the specified place but it goes to another place.

[image: link]

[link to code](https://pastebin.com/eevR2n6s) There are also `.cls` and several other `.sty` file. I'll add that if needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help others to help you by providing a [complete but minimal example document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem you encounter.

Comment: Thanks. I'm making changes in a template available on [sharelatex](sharelatex.com). Added the link.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you have to change `additional information` to your wished content:

```
\extrainfo{\faGithub\href{https://github.com/}{ name}}% <===============
```

Please see with the current version of `moderncv` (version 2.0.0) you can use command

```
\social[github]{jdoe}
```

to add your github informations.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontawesome}% <=============================================

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe} % <===============================================
\extrainfo{\faGithub\href{https://github.com/}{ name}}% <===============
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution for this but forgot to answer here. But I'm stuck on adding stackoverflow icon with link. Can I add it too? If there is one liner solution you can add here else I'll ask another question for that.

Comment: @Mensch Is there any recent documentation for the `moderncv` package? In `CTAN` only for `v0.6` documentation is available.