# ModernCV symbols (email, skype etc.)

Tags: symbols, moderncv, cv

I looked for the `moderncv` documentation, but without any success. I'd like to know the list of the symbols (email, skype etc.). Can you tell me if there is this list please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regarding email: `\emailsymbol`. Regarding skype: [Skype icon on moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/190954/134144)

Comment: if using the fontawesome fonts from your last question/answer then the symbols are documented in fontawesome  [readmeS](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=awesome) or the ctan font character listings such as https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

Comment: Useful reply @leandriis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is no documentation of class `moderncv`, only a very small one in  [version 0.6 on the github repository](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/tree/master/manual)  of the maintainer, but there are no more activities.

Because I told you in your last question about package `fontawesome` I suggest you use the following commands

```
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large\faMobilePhone}~}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {\faPhone~}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {{\small\faFax}~}                % alternative: \faPrint
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {{\small\faEnvelopeO}~}          % alternative: \faInbox
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {{\small\faGlobe}~}              % alternative: \faHome
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{{\small\faLinkedin}~}           % alternative: \faLinkedinSquare
\renewcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}    {{\small\faXing}~}               % alternative: \faXingSquare
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {{\small\faTwitter}~}            % alternative: \faTwitterSquare
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {{\small\faGithub}~}             % alternative: \faGithubSquare, \faGithubSquare
\renewcommand*{\gitlabsocialsymbol}  {{\small\faGitlab}~}
\renewcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol} {{\small\faSkype}~}
```

for the symbols you are searching for.

But if you want to use this symbols in the personal informations in the header/footer of an cv you need to add some more commands to your preamble -- depending on your used version of `moderncv`.

For example you can look to [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477971/16550) for using the command `\social` with more possibilities, used in version 2.0.0!  See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454628/16550).

To see a list of possible useable symbols for font awesome gave a look to the corresponding homepage of it: https://fontawesome.com/. There is a new fontawesome5 also available ...

I suggest to add the code you used to question to use your needed symbols in your cv. Then I can help you knowing excactly what you are having and doing ...

A last remark: to see the predefined and so available symbols in your used version of `moderncv` search for the file `moderncviconsawesome.sty` and `moderncviconsmarvosym.sty`. The latter is called by command `\moderncvicons{marvosym}` in version 2.0.0