# Moderncvhead and moderncvbodyi warnings - ModernCV

Tags: errors, templates, moderncv, warnings, cv

I did my CV by using Texmaker on a PC; when I open the file on another PC it does not work, in particular the software gives me the following messages (I downloaded and updated MikTek as well):

[image]

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman
% moderncv contiene anche i simboli del telefono, dell'email ecc

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
% L'opzione classic permette di inserire le informazioni personali (data di nascita, indirizzo, telefono, email) in alto a destr, accanto alla foto.

\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

%\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\newsavebox{\skypeicon}
\savebox{\skypeicon}{\includegraphics[height=.8\baselineskip]{skypefig}}
\newcommand{\skypesocialsymbol}{\usebox{\skypeicon}}
% Questo blocco di istruzioni serve per inserire il simbolo di Skype

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\MATLAB}{\textsc{Matlab}\xspace}
% Questo blocco di istruzioni serve per inserire il simbolo di MATLAB

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{G} % Your first name
\familyname{A} % Your last name


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CURRICULUM VITAE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CAMPI DI INTERESSE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Occupational Field}

\cvitem{}{
Academic and research field
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education and Training}

\cventry{}{Master's degree in robotics and automation engineering}{(in progress), University of Pisa}{Pisa (PI), Italy}{}
{
\begin{itemize}
\item Extracurricular exam: biomechanics of human motion (bionics engineering)
\end{itemize}
}
{}
\cventry{}{Bachelor's degree in biomedical engineering (industrial curriculum)}{University of Pisa}{Pisa (PI), Italy}{\textit{1}}
{
\begin{itemize}
\item Thesis: Reconfigurable electrochemical biosensor; it can be used in three different measurements modes (amperometric, potentiometric, electrochemical impedance spectroscopy)
\end{itemize}
}{}
\cventry{}{High school diploma (classical studies)}{Liceo Classico}{Italy}{\textit{1}}
{
%\begin{itemize}
%\item Tesi: La Natura.
%\item Materie: Latino, Greco, Inglese, Biologia, Chimica, Scienze Naturali, Fisica, Matematica, Storia, Geografia, Italiano.
%\end{itemize}
}{}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage % vado in una nuova pagina, altrimenti a pag 1 compare solo "Competenze informatiche" ed il resto è a pag 2
\section{Computer Skills}

\cvitem{}{C++, Atmel ATXMEGA256A3BU Microcontroller and Atmel Studio, LTspice, \MATLAB, Wolfram Mathematica, COMSOL Multiphysics (Structural Mechanics Module, Fluid Dynamics Module, Heat Transfer Module, Deformed Mesh Module, Material Library, Fluid-Structure Interaction), \LaTeX, Microsoft Windows, Microsoft Office.}


\end{document}
```

How can I solve these problems? If you need all the files I put them [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09789177764466671141).

Thank you so much.

Comment: this was a bug 4 years ago https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260446/what-does-you-have-requested-package-foo-but-the-package-provides-foo-me

Comment: Why do you not use `fontawesome` and `\faSkype` for the skype icon as already mentioned in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485923/16550 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has two parts:

1. The class `moderncv` in current version 2.0.0 has simply a bug, which is not corrected by the maintainer until today in the version on CTAN. On Github there is an corrected version, but it is not published on CTAN ... The usual workaround here is: simply ignore this warnings:

   ```
   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/moderncv\moderncvheadi.sty"

   LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadi',
              but the package provides `moderncvheadi'.
   ```

   Please see that should not be the ususal behaviour, but in this case you can ignore this warnings ... Hopefully the maintainer will soon correct this and some other bugs in the class ...
2. You showed the warning:

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
   (Font)              Font shape `T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 93.
   ```

   This warning comes from the usage of package `marvosym` with `pdflatex`. You can open your command line/Terminal/console and type the following two commands: `initexmf --mkmaps` and `initexmf --update-fndb` to get package `marvosym` working again ...

Comment: Hello @Mensch, sorry for the delay. Your solution is perfect; now it works very good.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi You are welcome!